# Does a clustered index make insertions slower than if the table is a heap?

Tags: sql-server

I have a logs table with millions of records. It is a heap without indexes. Would a clustered index make insertions slower?

Thanks in advance,

Ignacio

Comment: See what Kimberly Tripp (*Queen of Indexing*) has to say: "Inserts are faster in a clustered table (but only in the "right" clustered table) than compared to a heap" - reference: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the issue identified by @marc_s in a comment (See what Kimberly Tripp (Queen of Indexing) has to say: "Inserts are faster in a clustered table (but only in the "right" clustered table) than compared to a heap" - [reference](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)), the decision to use a heap versus using a clustered index is complicated and as in so many things related to databases, It Depends™.

You should take into consideration the source of the data you are inserting, whether it is sorted, whether you will be frequently deleting or updating rows in the table, whether you need to use Referential Integrity when relating to rows in the target table, etc, etc.

In short, only looking at insert speed may not give you the entire picture for performance.

Having said all that, if the clustered index key is defined in the same way as the source data is sorted, then most likely a clustered index insert will be faster than a heap.

Comment: I was thinking about a row ID index, being a primary key, with autoincreae identity. A dummy field in fact, since the table log is not consulted.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [benchmarks](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4961/sql-server-insert-performance-for-clustered-indexes-vs-heap-tables/) showing the a clustered index is faster even for inserts.